# how to block specific traffic through fiddler?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I'm in fiddler before request:

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)

if (oS.fullUrl.Contains("ss")

// Block this traffic only
```

I'd like to block this traffic specifically. Is it something that can be done?

Comment: You may search for documentation of Fiddler itself. Google would do better than Stack Exchange in this sense. [that is, please show signs you actually did research]

Comment: well I can show what I found but is useless... I always find different code to block all of them no matter the words I used. I didn't think it would be useful to write about those.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/manipulating-traffic-with-fiddler-extensions suggests using the FailSession command.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer. However this solution is one that blocks all the traffic after this code is done.

Comment: Oh, the FailSession command fails all requests instead of just one? That appears to be more of a bug rather than something normal.

Comment: well actually it fails the browser when I use it... so it doesn't block request, but since the page load is stopped, subsequent requests of a page load are not received.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an autoresponder which just returns 500 or whatever.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'm currently on another task, but when I'm back to it I'll keep you updated. I work with C# however (tag) so I'll look on how to do it in C#, unless you already know?